# LibreOffice Base won't install

Tags: libreoffice

I have tried to install Libre Office Base with Ubuntu Center and Synaptic with no success. Ubuntu 12.04.
I get the following message with Synaptic:
Could not mark all packages for installation or upgrade

The following packages have unresolvable dependencies. Make sure that all required repositories are added and enabled in the preferences.

libreoffice-base:
Depends:libreoffice-core but it's not going to be installed
Depends:libreoffice-base-core but it's not going to be installed
Depends: libreoffice-java-common but it's not going to be installed

I got a dialog box before this message telling me to mark things, but that didn't seem to work either. Thank you!

Comment: try this in a terminal and report results please "sudo apt-get install liberoffice-base", it will attempt to install the liberoffice base

Comment: Thank you! I get the following message: Unable to locate package liberoffice-base

Comment: "sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base" its libre :)

Comment: yes sorry a typo

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` in terminal or "Reload" in Synaptic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-3-5
sudo update
sudo install libreoffice-base
```

for some reason, your system can't find the libreoffice packages , but the commands above would add a repository where such packages are available
the first command add a repo
the second perform an update to the packages list and last actually perform the install

Comment: Its was typo mistake. See again the comments.